# Change background image of a tile

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-layout, image

I am trying to change the background image of a tile in the home page. Can this be done using any OOTB techniques or using CSS?

[image]

Comment: You would need to override the back ground image of `<span style="height:150px; width:150px; position:relative; display:inline-block; overflow:hidden;"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/gettingstarted.png?rev=41" style="left:-300px; top:-150px; position:absolute;" onerror="return SP.UI.PromotedLinks.BackgroundImage.OnLoadError(this);" alt="Share your site."></span>` for the particular cell you want.